# What advantage would there be using a Listener as a Service instead of a Service

Tags: php, service, symfony, listener

FYI I'm just getting started with Symfony, with that said...

What advantage would there be using a Listener as a Service instead of a Service?

Looking over the docs I see I can use a Listener as a Service:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

But I could also use the Event Dispatcher:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html

to get the same functionality or am I missing something?

What I'm looking to do is create a service that listens for custom events and I'm a little confused on the route I should take with the above scenario. I have seen some posts about each setup but nothing comparing the two and the differences.

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, events in a Symfony application are similar to events in JavaScript: instead of listening to mostly UI related events (such as mouse clicks, hovers etc) you're listening to arbitrary events in the application (such as exceptions getting throws, response being sent, user being created etc).

EventDispatcher is built around the [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern. For any occurring events the dispatcher notifies all the registered listeners about the event. Surely you could retrieve the dispatcher from the service container and register the listener by hand, but this doesn't allow us to listen to events being fired beforehand. Even worse, the listener is only registered in that controller action.

By configuring the listener to be a service, you're essentially letting the framework do the registering process itself. If you have a look at `app/cache/dev/appDevDebugContainer.php` (can be a bit different name, writing this off top of my head) and search for `event_dispatcher`, you should be able to see how the events have been automatically registered.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, an even listener "listens" to events, while an event dispatcher "dispatchs" (sends) them.

If you want a service that listen to custom events (i.e. events that you create), then you would have to create both an event dispatcher to send the events and an even listener to listen for them

Comment: yes but the docs for "Listener as an Service" look to also include the service functionality in the Listener itself instead of calling the Service. or am I missing something again

Comment: The listener IS a service in this case

Comment: Yes I get this, my question is why would I do this over calling a service in the service class? Is there some benefit in doing this?